# Can iTunes be made to play Apple ProRes files?

Tags: itunes, macos, video, encoding

My videos encoded as Apple ProRes are playable in Quicktime but not in iTunes.  Is there anything I can do to make iTunes play them?

[Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2729) suggests to me that iTunes can play any .MOV file:

> QuickTime and MPEG-4 movie files that end in ".mov", ".m4v", or ".mp4"
>   and are playable in QuickTime Player.

but this does not seem to be the case in my testing, instead I find that I am unable to add the files to the iTunes library. There is no error dialog.

Comment: What happens when you try to play them?

Comment: @tubedogg I have updated my question.

Comment: i tried for some hours yesterday and *was not able* to get iTunes 12.x working with these formats/codecs.

Comment: @bMalum Ha!  Well if nobody else comes through with a solution you should post that as an answer so I can award the bounty to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 24 of July I tried for some hours to get iTunes 12.x (actual version at this time) to play other 3rd Party Codecs. In short: I was **not** successful. iTunes has changed a lot, so none of the *older* hacks work anymore.

I'm very interested in a solution for this problem, because I have a lot of FLAC-Files I would love to manage in iTunes. If I find a solution I will update this answer and provide a "Tutorial".

Answer (score -2):

You could try this really old hint to [Make iTunes 6 accept non-native video formats](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051013124423475), which explains how it used to be possible to add .AVI and other formats that iTunes does not support natively to its video library by using the Saving As… command and creating a small reference .MOV movie. iTunes did accept these reference movies in its library, while it played the original referenced movie when instructed to play the added ones.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I find that when I open the reference movie a conversion to H264 occurs.  Even then I am not able to add the converted movie to iTunes.